# What is the best method for socket.io + express session support?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm new to node.js and I can't seem to find a good method for creating a session that can be interacted by from both express and socket.io. I have tried many solutions posted, but none seem to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May I have the exact code snippet you are working with?  I was able to get a basic chat app and multiplayer game from sample to run from node and would take a look at the sample you are trying to use.

In a nutshell, you need to establish a variable to io to require sockets.io module.  From there you will also need to write all potential socket messages to be sent and received on your app.js file.  I took this from [Michael Mukhin's Chat tutorial:](http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/)

With Node installed create a new folder for your app and create a blank file named **package.json**. Node.JS reads this file to determine the dependencies required to run your application.  In this package.json file copy the following:

```
{
 "name": "mukhin_chat",
 "description": "example chat application with socket.io",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.4.6",
    "socket.io": "0.8.4"
 }
```

}

now go back to the command line and type "npm install" to include express and socket.io. Create a 2nd file called **app.js** and use the following:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

Finally, create the Client facing **index.html** file that will be run and displayed to users connecing to your app:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>USERS</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

Run the server itself with: node app.js

in the command prompt window.

Key takeaways:

1. Declaring all potential sockets.io activity with a global "io"
   variable.
2. socket.action = updates a specific socket
3. sockets.action = updates ALL sockets.
4. it has io in the name meaning sockets will only have two values, on
   or off Thus treat socket.on as type to 'trigger' for a function.
5. See how the app.js (server-side data) has different functions defined for each of the various 'socket.on' conditions?  That is how sockets is connecting to your index.html ant talking to your app users. (client side data)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. A suggestion it will be good if you can update your code for  expressJS 4.x, because you are using "express": "2.4.6" which is too old version. Please use the never version. Many things have changed since then. Best will be if you write with Express 4.9 Thanks.

Comment: lets be sure to clarify this: not my code, michael's :)